# How to use QThread when application starts

Tags: python, pyqt

I have loadData() function which parses big XML file and insert data into QTableWidget. Function is executed when application starts = GUI freezes for a moment and I don't want that. This is my WorkerThread class:

```
class WorkerThread(QThread):

def __init__(self):
    QThread.__init__(self)

def __del__(self):
    self.wait()

def run(self):
    QtApp().loadData()
```

And this is what I have tried:

```
class QtApp(QMainWindow):

def __init__(self):

    QMainWindow.__init__(self)


    self.ui = uic.loadUi('gui.ui', self)

    self.ui.show()


    self.workerThread = WorkerThread()
    self.workerThread.start()
```

It just loads the main window again and again. Eventually application crashes. Exiting workerThread at the end of loadData() does not help.

Comment: A guess the second snippet is in a class called `QtApp`?  Then creating an instance starts a thread which creates another instance of `QtApp` in its `run()` method which starts a thread…  Just don't create new `QtApp` instances in the thread. Maybe you want to use the already _existing_ instance, then pass that to the `WorkerThread`s init. Next problem is `__del__()`: just don't implement this methode. Ever. Unless you know exactly why you shouldn't implement it.

Comment: Okay now I understand what the problem is, even though I don't know how to solve it yet. I am not sure how to pass that existing instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a possible solution:

```
class WorkerThread(QThread):
    # define a new signal which will be emitted when data loading finishes
    load_data_finished = pyqtSignal(list)

    def __init__(self):
        QThread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        # load data in new thread
        self.load_data()

    def load_data(self):
        data = []
        #
        # load your data here ...
        # example:
        data.append(1)
        data.append(2)
        data.append(3)
        #
        # when loading data finishes, emit the signal
        self.load_data_finished.emit(data)


class QtApp(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        # load UI...
        self.show()

        self.workerThread = WorkerThread()
        # connect the thread signal to a slot defined in this class
        self.workerThread.load_data_finished.connect(self.on_load_data_finished)
        self.workerThread.start()

    def on_load_data_finished(self, data):
        print("data loaded: ", data)


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
main_window = QtApp()
```

app.exec_()

Comment: Thanks, it worked! I read that gui updating should be done only in main thread, so I still need to pass list variable from load_data() to main thread but maybe it's another question.

Comment: I edited the answer with a more complete example, where data is passed through the signal to the slot.